# Next js nested dynamic routes: data fetching via getstaticprops with shared data between routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to build a next.js app with nested dynamic routes and shared data between the routes. The file structure looks like this:

```
-pages
  -/level1
  -/[level1_id].js
    -index.js
    -/level2
      -/[level2_id].js
        -index.js
```

The page component for Level2 looks like this for now (level 1 looks basically the same)

```
const Level2 = ({ data }) => {

  console.log("Level2 ID:", data.data.id)

    return (
        <div >
          {data.data.id}
      </div>
    )
}

export default Level2


export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

  return {
    paths: [ { params : {slug: ['1'], level1_id: '1', level2_id: '1'}}],
    fallback: false
  }
}


export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {

  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/level2/${context.params.level2_id}`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    }
  }
}
```

And the API simply returns the level ID for now:

```
export default (req, res) => {
  const { level2_id } = req.query;
  const data = { id: level2_id }

  res.status(200).json({ data })
}
```

My question is:

Is there a way to get the data for level1 without clientside data fetching when someone visits the site via the path
*/level1/1/level2/1* ?

Level 2 depends on data that is fetched (and statically exported) in level 1 (not just the ID of level 1 as in the example). When I navigate on the homepage from *level1/1* to *level1/1/level2/1* I simply share that data with react context. But if someone visits my site via the nested link, that data is obviously not there. I'd love to find a way to provide it using *getstaticprops* (or something along the lines) so the site can be exported statically without the need of a running api and client side data fetching.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You may want to read this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11272
Basically you need to abstract away your data fetching methods into a lib. You may use the filesystem to cache some data. Then  you can simply use your methods in both pages. It's a bit tedious but there is no simpler way at the moment, I think the complexity steams from the fact that build is parallelized so sharing data is not obvious.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This looks more complicated than I hoped but I'll definitely have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the file-based cache solution for future reference. I needed it for my own project:
[jrandeniya/nextjs-ssg-contentful-cached](https://github.com/jrandeniya/nextjs-ssg-contentful-cached).

It's in Typescript with build-time type generation and caching calls between `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`. Contentful just happens to be the data-source but you can swap it out to your own.